# Trouble with ng-repeat in svg polygon tag

Tags: angularjs, svg

I have a json file of the format [{name:"blabla", "svg": "147,87,156,59,161,59,153,89,149,88"}, more... ].

I want to use it in an agnularJS ng-repeat to create svg polygons like this:

```
 <svg>
       <polygon ng-repeat="item in svgList" points="{{item.svg}}" 
       class="{{item.name}}"</polygon>                   
 </svg>
```

The polygons are rendered but i get the error message:

Error:  attribute points: Expected number, "{{item.svg}}".

I added the list below to se what happend and i don't get any errors from it.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat ="item in svgList">{{item.svg}}</li>
</ul>
```

Why is a polygon element diffrent form a li element?

svgList is created from my json file. Code follows:

```
$http.get('svgTest.json').then(function success(response) {
            $scope.svgList = response.data;
            console.log("ok");
        },function error(response) {
            console.log("error");
        })
```

Comment: what is in `svgList`, show your controller code

Comment: I read my json file into svgList. Code added to post

Comment: It's an issue of browser behavior of validating SVG before render, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to browser behavior of validating SVG before rendering, This can be fixed with `ngAttr` attribute binding. [Read More](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#-ngattr-for-binding-to-arbitrary-attributes).

Just decorate the `points` attribute like `ng-attr-points` will fix your issue..  See this working [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qc3qc61g/)